# Why can't i run my file on Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I get this error:

> Error running 'filename.py': Cannot run program "/home/my_name/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python" (in directory "/home/my_name/repo_name/ocr"): error=2, No such file or directory

`/home/my_name/PycharmProjects/untitled/file.py` is the first file I created after installing PyCharm to make sure it's working then deleted it.

I want to run filename.py which is in `ocr` but I'm getting the above error.

I tried in the cmd `python filename.py` and worked just fine, so it's definitely related to PyCharm.

How to properly adjust my files once and for all, since I just installed it?

Comment: Does /home/my_name/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python still exist?

Comment: No it doesn't, i deleted it. I got out of pycharm then back again and it pops up the edit configuration telling me to choose an interpreter and it's blank.

Comment: Then that is your issue, choose another interpreter and it should work

Comment: It's completely blank as i don't have options to choose from, should i give it a path, if so to my env or somewhere else (i know probably to the python.exe but where).

Comment: You are on linux or windows

Comment: Running on Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error contains this:

```
Cannot run program "/home/my_name/PycharmProjects/untitled/venv/bin/python"
```

which indicates, that nothing is wrong with your file, but, instead pycharm cannot locate the python interpreter. It is configured to use a venv one in a project folder "untitled" which, as you said, you deleted. You should choose another interpreter

Comment: This is what i added there `/home/my_name/repo_name/ocr/env/bin/python3.5` but didn't work

Comment: does that exist and you can type the exact same path in the terminal?

Comment: Yes i can reach till /bin using cd since python3.5 is not a directory but it's visualy there could it possibly be cause i'm running pycharm from terminal using `./pycharm.sh` and don't have it as a `fixed` item.

Comment: does an interactive python shell start when you type `/home/my_name/repo_name/ocr/env/bin/python3.5` in the terminal

Comment: `./pycharm.sh` is not an issue, since that is how you are supposed to start it. It also works just fine in my interpreter

Comment: Yes it does, `Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 ] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print(1)
1
`

Comment: Interesting. Can you make sure `settings - Project - Project Interpreter` is set correctly?

Comment: Next you can try to open a python console inside pycharm

Comment: before i do is there a way to make that pycharm icon always out as i always have to run that ./pycharm.sh command and i have to stop it  if i want to run anything else in terminal basically killing pycharm.

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. add this to your bashrc: `alias pycharm="<path to pycharm>/bin/pycharm.sh"` 2. in your command line do `pycharm &`. The first lets you start pycharm from wherever, the second one starts pycharm with `&` which means "run in background" which lets you still use the shell

Comment: I went into settings and it still shows project:untitled although i have deleted that one, i checked the path and they created another folder called untitled although i deleted the first, weird, not to mention i'm not able to delete it adjust it or anything

Comment: Go to File->Close Project and then create a new one in which you want to work. During this process you can also check to create a new venv for that project. After that just copy your python file into the project directory and it should be working

Comment: I'll uninstall pycharm then install it again and delete everything related to it, i'll yet yo0u know hopw it goes

Comment: OK trying to give the new environment path to my env but it says it's not empty..isn't it supposed to take the path of the env in the repo

Comment: You have two choices: New environment: Then you need to give it a new path, where it should create a new new environment OR use existing interpreter. If you have some interpreter you want to use, then use that one. However I would advice against having the virtual environment as part of your repository and create a new one on each computer you are working on

Comment: Finally it works, thanks for the time and help mate.